# I am trying to loop through a multidimentional array and display info in a contact card, but can't get all the info to show

Tags: php, loops

So I just want to go through the $rows array, display $rows[0] as one contact and $rows[1] as another.  For some reason, the information in  is not looped, it only shows the second entry (or if there are more than two, whatever the last entry is).  The thing I am not understanding is why when I echo the information without a div, it loops through and displays information for both entries.  I've tried using both foreach loops and for ($i=0; $i

```
                $rows[0] = array(
                    'picture'       => 'userImage',//$jpeg[$i],
                    'givenname'         => '',//$info[$i]["givenname"][0],
                    'sn'            => '',//$info[$i]["sn"][0],
                    'mail'          => '@.com',//$info[$i]["mail"][0],
                );
                $rows[1] = array(
                    'picture'       => 'userImage',//$jpeg[$i],
                    'givenname'         => '',//$info[$i]["givenname"][0],
                    'sn'            => '',//$info[$i]["sn"][0],
                    'mail'          => '@.com',//$info[$i]["mail"][0],
                );
                    //User contact card
                    for ($i=0; $i<count($rows); $i++){

                        $strCard[$i] = '';
                        $strCard[$i] .= "   <div class='search-card'>" . $rows[$i]['picture'] . "
                                <p><b>" . $rows[$i]['givenname'] . " " .  $rows[$i]['sn']. "</b></p>
                                <p><a href='mailto:" .  $rows[$i]['mail'] . "'>" .  $rows[$i]['mail']. "</a></p>
                                <div class='member-roles'>";

                        $strCard[$i] .= "<table>";
                        $strCard[$i] .= "<tr><th>Role</th><th>Centre</th></tr>";

                    echo $i.'===='.$rows[$i]['picture'].'<br />';
                    echo $i.'===='.$rows[$i]['givenname'].'<br />';
                    echo $i.'===='.$rows[$i]['sn'].'<br />';
                    echo $i.'===='.$rows[$i]['mail'].'<br />';
            }
    foreach ($strCard as $key => $value) {
        return $strCard[$key];
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by return? is the code in a function?

Comment: $strCard[$i] = ''; needs to be outside the loop to start the variable, otherwise everytime the loop starts, it writes over the contents.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are probably executing this code inside of a function and using `return` instead of `echo`....taken from the php manual:

`"If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call...."`

https://www.php.net/return

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the value of the foreach loop like this

```
foreach ($strCard as $value) {          
    return $value
}
```

Im not sure how is this useful for you, if you want to return the whole string you can try something like this

```
$string = '';
foreach ($strCard as $value) {          
    $string.=$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but it seems like maybe you're wanting this

```
        for ($i=0; $i<count($rows); $i++){

                    $strCard[$i] = '';
                    $strCard[$i] .= "   <div class='search-card'>" . $rows[$i]['picture'] . "
                            <p><b>" . $rows[$i]['givenname'] . " " .  $rows[$i]['sn']. "</b></p>
                            <p><a href='mailto:" .  $rows[$i]['mail'] . "'>" .  $rows[$i]['mail']. "</a></p>
                            <div class='member-roles'>";

                    $strCard[$i] .= "<table>";
                    $strCard[$i] .= "<tr><th>Role</th><th>Centre</th></tr>";
        }
        foreach ($strCard as $cardEntry) {
            echo $cardEntry;
        }
```

Or to simplify it

```
        for ($i=0; $i<count($rows); $i++){

                    $strCard = '';
                    $strCard .= "   <div class='search-card'>" . $rows[$i]['picture'] . "
                            <p><b>" . $rows[$i]['givenname'] . " " .  $rows[$i]['sn']. "</b></p>
                            <p><a href='mailto:" .  $rows[$i]['mail'] . "'>" .  $rows[$i]['mail']. "</a></p>
                            <div class='member-roles'>";

                    $strCard .= "<table>";
                    $strCard .= "<tr><th>Role</th><th>Centre</th></tr>";

                    echo $strCard;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

$strCard[$i] = ''; needs to be outside the loop to start the variable, otherwise everytime the loop starts, it writes over the contents.